# How can I pass variable into an evaluate function that evaluates an async function using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer. The variable passed doesn't work. I need this variable to be used inside the browser's context. Here's the stripped down version of the code :

```
let currentPost = 1;

await page.evaluate(async (currentPost) => {
    await new Promise((currentPost, resolve, reject) => {
        
        var timer = setInterval(() => {

            console.log(currentPost);
            resolve();
            
        }, 100);

    }); 

}, currentPost);
```

Comment: It's `new Promise((resolve, reject)`. Remove that `currentPost` from there. And don't `await` it, return it

Comment: Also, you have probably issues with variable shadowing since you gave 3 variables the same name in different contexts, try being a bit more creative with names ;)

Comment: I assumed copies are being made and referenced internally with its own unique references. But ill take that into account. thanks. I will try your suggetion and get back to you. Appreciate the prompt response. Also, I'm executing some tasks inside the promise that i need to be completed before being returned, so, will returning the new promise achieve that as you suggested?

Comment: @RonB OP should be OK after removing `currentPost` from the promise callback parameter list because that whole function is serialized and executed in browser context by Puppeteer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise accepts in two arguments: resolve and reject. remove the current Post arg and it will work as expected.

```
let currentPost = 1;

await page.evaluate(async (currentPost) => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        var timer = setInterval(() => {

            console.log(currentPost);
            resolve();
            
        }, 100);

    }); 

}, currentPost);
```

Comment: Trying that now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome my friend @JohnYepthomi. would appreciate the vote up and if you can accept my answer (:

Comment: I did , was honored to do so. :)

Comment: Hmm, i don't think the answer was accepted my friend, can you try again @JohnYepthomi?

Comment: Right, my browser was acting up, sorry for that. You should see it now.